# How to add additional control key?

Tags: xmodmap, xkb

I am using xkb to add an additional control key as follows:

```
key <HENK> { [  Control_R                 ] };
```

However, it does not work.

I even tried xmodmap without success:

```
xmodmap -e "keysym Henkan_Mode = Control_R"
```

I had no problems adding additional shift key using similar codes as above. So I don't understand why the same code does not work with the control key.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
modifier_map Control {  <HENK>  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem; thanks for pointing me in the right direction by mentioning of the pre-existing modifier maps.

Below, I remap the Japanese special keys to extra controls and alt:

```
# Make use of a Japanese keyboard extra keys, if present.
xmodmap -e 'add control = Control_L Control_R Muhenkan Henkan_Mode'
xmodmap -e 'add mod1 = Alt_L Alt_R Meta_L Hiragana_Katakana'
# Clear keys original meaning
xmodmap -e 'keysym Muhenkan = Control_L'
xmodmap -e 'keysym Henkan_Mode = Control_R'
xmodmap -e 'keysym Hiragana_Katakana = Alt_R'
```